# Gedit: syntax highlighting of echoing self-closing XHTML tags in JavaScript in PHP

Tags: debian, gedit, syntax-highlighting

Reproduction:

- In Gedit, open a new file and manually select the syntax highlighting language (at the bottom right) to `PHP`.
- Write some javascript in `<script>` tags
- Within the `<script>` tags, echo some XHTML with self-closing tags
- Note that all of the code that follows is no longer syntax highlighted

Alternatively, paste this in:

```
<?php
    echo 'hello - this is still syntax highlighted! <span id="foo"></span>';
?>

<script>
    myApp: {
        foobar: function() {
            document.id('foo').set('html', '<hr />');
            alert('uh-oh, what happened to the syntax highlighting? This string is no longer coloured.');
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    echo 'syntax highlighting returns after the closing </script> tag';
?>
```

It's not a big deal, since I can work around it right now by replacing all self-closing tags with their HTML 4 equivalents (e.g. `<input></input>`), but I was wondering if anybody else dealt with this problem...

Comment: Surely this belongs on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Possibly - but since it's a Unixish question, and not really related to programming, I felt it belonged here.

Comment: @dmckee Since it's about Gedit (yeah, it took me a while to figure that out, I've clarified the title), it's on-topic here. If the question had been about PHP, it would have been off-topic.